# how to make "reset sorting" button for listview in kendo ui

Tags: listview, sorting, kendo-ui, reset-button

I have a `ListView` with enabled column sorting. I want to make a reset button which will reset the column sorting and the `ListView` will look same as on page loading. Similar to reloading the entire page, but just reloading the `ListView`.

This Is my code:

```
 <button onclick="clearSorts()" style="float: right;" class="k-button" type="button" value="edit">Clear Sort</button>

$("#clearSorts()").click(function(e) {
     dataSource.sort({});
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just read the DataSource again

```
 var grid = $("#ProposalGrid").data("kendoGrid");
                    grid.dataSource.page(1); // or
                     grid.dataSource.read();
```

Answer (score 1):

`dataSource.sort({})` should remove all the sorting applied

Comment: See [`filter`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#methods-filter) for more information

Comment: I have code like this:
<button id="clearSorts()" style="float: right;" class="k-button" type="button" value="edit">Clear Sort</button>

$("#clearSorts()").click(function(e) {
         dataSource.sort({});
        });

Where is my error, because it does not work this way.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error.

```
 function clearSorts(e) {
        var grid = $("#ProposalGrid").data("kendoGrid");
       // grid.dataSource.page(1); // or
        grid.dataSource.sort({});
```